# sIFR links are not visible

Tags: hyperlink, sifr, invisible

I'm trying to get a link in a truetype fornt with sIFR3. It's working fine for all ordinary <h1> and <h2> items, but not for links within a <h2>. sIFR is replacing the <a> correctly, but the result is invisible. When I click the area where the text should be, it follows the link. Even with a pointer cursor. But where's my text?

Replacer:

```
 sIFR.replace(vagroundbtf, {
   selector: '#summary_normalx h2'
   , css: [
      '.sIFR-root { color:#000000; font-weight : bold;}  a {color:#333333; text-decoration: none;} '
       ] 
   ,wmode: 'transparent'
    });
```

HTML-snippet:

```
 <div id="summary_normal">
  <div id="article_92" class="entry clearing">
   <div id="summary_normalx">
    <h2>
     <a href="some/link" id="show_article_92" title="Show">This is the title</a>
    </h2> 
    :
```

BTW: when I remove the css-clause, links are visible in the right font but in default look (blue underlined).

Any ideas?

Roel

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  sIFR.replace(vagroundbtf, {
   selector: '#summary_normalx h2'
   , css: [
      '.sIFR-root { color:#000000; font-weight : bold;}',
      'a {color:#333333; text-decoration: none;}'
       ] 
   ,wmode: 'transparent'
    });
```

btw. I do prefer Cufón over sIFR nowadays